# Facebook page tab content width set to 810px, getting cropped horizontally and vertically

Tags: facebook, width, facebook-canvas

I'm trying to create a Facebook Page Tab using a custom app and I cant figure out how to set the width correctly. The content is 810px, the page tab width is set to Wide (810px)and I've tried setting the canvas width/height to both fixed and fluid, neither setting seems to change anything:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROi0P.png

and yet I'm stuck with a horizontal scroll bar on the page tab:

https://www.facebook.com/NTCLA/app_270240146413176

How can I get rid of the scroll bars?

*****UPDATE*****

After more scouring, I found the answer. Here it is for anyone that is having the same issue!

http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-iframe-apps-getting-rid-of-scrollbars/

Answer (score 0):

To save some peeps time who might still be having an issue, after the hyperarts code, I was able to get kill that vertical bar on the right by adding the overflow css to both html and body.